# error in DRUPAL with respect to mysql_num_rows()

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

I am new to drupal and trying to execute some database related basic query. I need to count the number of affected rows in a table.
I tried with following codes :

```
  $query1 = "SELECT user_type,user_staus FROM `login_info` WHERE username='{$username}'   
  AND password='{$password}' LIMIT 1";
  $fetched = db_query($query1);
  //check if record exists otherwise you would receive another notice that can 
  //break redirect functionality
  if (mysql_num_rows($fetched))
  {
     $record = db_fetch_assoc($fetched);
    // make sure that value is integer
    if ((int)$record["user_staus"])
   {
       exit("Please login after some time");
   }
   else
  {  ------- codes ----  }
```

But I am getting following errors :

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in eval() (line 53 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(74) : eval()'d code).

And then when I am trying with **db_num_rows**, I am getting following errors :

Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_num_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(74) : eval()'d code on line 53

I am very new to DRUPAL, Can anyone please help me out. Many many thanks in advance .

Comment: Does echo mysql_num_rows($fetched); return anything?

Comment: Thanks... at least 1 person got time to help me out... No,,, Its not returning anything... But m getting continuous errors... errors are there with db_query($query1) also...  :(

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\extract.php on line

Comment: I am keeping code (extract.php) inside floder htdocs/drupal and calling by creating a basic page (under CONTENT) in PHP. I simply have written <?php include "extract.php"; ?> :(

Comment: Migrating to chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/7310/error-in-drupal-with-respect-to-mysql-num-rows?tab=general

Comment: Above code I had written in basic page under PHP-Filter option. But now I am just calling it as I've mentioned in my last comment. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As covered in the chat room, you're not connecting to the database using this external code.

You need to go into your themes folder and start in there. This way you will be connected to the database and the Drupal core etc.

If I were you I would start at the proper beginning with some tutorials. The Drupal ones on the official site are very good and are how I got started.

http://drupal.org/documentation/customization/tutorials

Good luck.